# Help identifying a story about siblings and ghosts

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a book that was vaguely described to me, so the information I have is only secondhand. I've attempted to find it on my own, but have had no such luck. Here are the facts as they were told to me:

1. The story centers on two siblings - a boy and a girl.
2. The story is set in New York (possibly some other metropolis?)
3. The story involves spirits of each borough that are only constrained to the borough in which they lived - a Queens ghost can't leave Queens, Bronx can't leave Bronx, etc.
4. It was almost certainly a YA novel.
5. It was part of a series, with each title taking the form "_____ of _____".

Other vague information is that it was kind of magical realism and incorporated the history of the city. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Point 3 seems to imply point 2 **must** be New York. Can you clarify how point 3 would be different if it were some other metropolis?

Comment: @ToddWilcox Possibly, it could have been some other historical city with well known neighborhoods. The person telling me was pretty sure it was New York City, but didn't rule out the possibility of other cities such as Paris and it's neighborhoods of the Ile de la Cite, Champs Elysees, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If the work in question is recent, the description could fit Victoria Schwab's ongoing series "City of Ghosts" (2018), "Tunnel of Bones" (2019), "Bridge of Souls" (2021).

The first is set in Edinburgh, the second in Paris, and the third in New Orleans. Here is part of the blurb for "Bridge of Souls":

> Cass might have this ghost hunting thing down. After all, she and her
> ghost best friend Jacob have survived two haunted cities while
> travelling for her parents' TV show. But nothing can prepare Cass for
> New Orleans, a city bursting with old magic, secret societies, and
> scary seances.

Note, however, that Cass and Jacob are not siblings. So - maybe?

If this isn't the right answer, can you give some estimate on how old these books would be?

Comment: Hm. The person who read them suggested it was read during her highschool years of 2014-2018, so while it's not a perfect match it could have been City of Ghosts!

Comment: Nope! Verified with the person, and this book was read around 2010-2011. Good sleuthing, though!